# Using CopyIndex and listKeys in outputs section

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

I'm trying to get the primaryConnectionStrings from an aRM template that creates multiple notification hubs

But I get this error

```
Error: Code=InvalidTemplate; Message=Deployment template validation failed: 'The template output 'connectionStrings' at line '291' and column '30' is not valid: The 
template function 'copyIndex' is not expected at this location. The function can only be used in a resource with copy specified. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-copy for usage details.. Please see 
https://aka.ms/arm-template-expressions for usage details.'.
```

I am clearly missing what this actually means as I've tried various incarnations of the template all of which have a copy for the resource.

I've tried this with a nested template (apologies if i've mangled the template, just removed some extraneous items):

```
    "resources": [
    {
        "type": "Microsoft.NotificationHubs/namespaces",
        "apiVersion": "2017-04-01",
        "name": "[parameters('notificationHubName')]",
        "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
        "tags": {
            "Environment": "[parameters('environment')]",
            "DisplayName": "Notification Hub Namespace"
        },
        "sku": {
            "name": "[parameters('notificationHubSku')]"
        },
        "kind": "NotificationHub",
        "properties": {
            "namespaceType": "NotificationHub"
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "Microsoft.NotificationHubs/namespaces/AuthorizationRules",
        "apiVersion": "2017-04-01",
        "name": "[concat(parameters('notificationHubName'), '/RootManageSharedAccessKey')]",
        "tags": {
            "Environment": "[parameters('environment')]",
            "DisplayName": "Notification Hub Namespace Auth Rules"
        },
        "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.NotificationHubs/namespaces', parameters('notificationHubName'))]"
        ],
        "properties": {
            "rights": [
                "Listen",
                "Manage",
                "Send"
            ]
        }
    },      
    {
        "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
        "apiVersion": "2018-05-01",
        "name": "[concat('nestedTemplate', copyIndex('notificationHubEntities'))]",
        "copy": {
            "name": "notificationHubEntities",
            "count": "[length(parameters('notificationHubEntities'))]"
        },
        "properties": {
            "mode": "Incremental",
            "template": {
                "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
                "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
                "resources": [
                    {
                        "type": "Microsoft.NotificationHubs/namespaces/notificationHubs",
                        "apiVersion": "2017-04-01",
                        "name": "[concat(parameters('notificationHubName'), '/', parameters('notificationHubEntities')[copyIndex('notificationHubEntities')])]",
                        "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
                        "tags": {
                            "Environment": "[parameters('environment')]",
                            "DisplayName": "Notification Hubs"
                        },                           
                        "dependsOn": [
                            "[resourceId('Microsoft.NotificationHubs/namespaces', parameters('notificationHubName'))]"
                        ],
                        "properties": {
                            "authorizationRules": []
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "Microsoft.NotificationHubs/namespaces/notificationHubs/authorizationRules",
                        "apiVersion": "2017-04-01",
                        "name": "[concat(parameters('notificationHubName'), '/',parameters('notificationHubEntities')[copyIndex('notificationHubEntities')],'/DefaultFullSharedAccessSignature')]",                           
                        "tags": {
                            "Environment": "[parameters('environment')]",
                            "DisplayName": "Notification Hub Auth Rules"
                        },
                        "dependsOn": [
                            "[resourceId('Microsoft.NotificationHubs/namespaces/notificationHubs',parameters('notificationHubName'), parameters('notificationHubEntities')[copyIndex('notificationHubEntities')])]",
                            "[resourceId('Microsoft.NotificationHubs/namespaces', parameters('notificationHubName'))]"
                        ],
                        "properties": {
                            "rights": [
                                "Listen",
                                "Manage",
                                "Send"
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                ],
                "outputs" : {
                    "connectionString" : {
                        "type" : "object",
                        "value": "[listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.NotificationHubs/namespaces/NotificationHubs/AuthorizationRules',parameters('notificationHubName'), parameters('notificationHubEntities')[copyIndex('notificationHubEntities')], 'DefaultFullSharedAccessSignature'),'2016-03-01').primaryConnectionString]"                            
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
],
"outputs": {
    "connectionStrings" :
    {
        "type": "array",
        "value": "[reference(concat('nestedTemplate', copyIndex('notificationHubEntities'))).outputs.connectionString.value]"
    }
}
```

}

I've also tried with this:

```
  "resources": [
    {
        "type": "Microsoft.NotificationHubs/namespaces",
        "apiVersion": "2017-04-01",
        "name": "[parameters('notificationHubName')]",
        "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
        "tags": {
            "Environment": "[parameters('environment')]",
            "DisplayName": "Notification Hub Namespace"
        },
        "sku": {
            "name": "[parameters('notificationHubSku')]"
        },
        "kind": "NotificationHub",
        "properties": {
            "namespaceType": "NotificationHub"
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "Microsoft.NotificationHubs/namespaces/AuthorizationRules",
        "apiVersion": "2017-04-01",
        "name": "[concat(parameters('notificationHubName'), '/RootManageSharedAccessKey')]",
        "tags": {
            "Environment": "[parameters('environment')]",
            "DisplayName": "Notification Hub Namespace Auth Rules"
        },
        "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.NotificationHubs/namespaces', parameters('notificationHubName'))]"
        ],
        "properties": {
            "rights": [
                "Listen",
                "Manage",
                "Send"
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "Microsoft.NotificationHubs/namespaces/notificationHubs",
        "apiVersion": "2017-04-01",
        "name": "[concat(parameters('notificationHubName'), '/', parameters('notificationHubEntities')[copyIndex()])]",
        "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
        "tags": {
            "Environment": "[parameters('environment')]",
            "DisplayName": "Notification Hubs"
        },
        "copy": {
            "name": "addNotificationHub",
            "count": "[length(parameters('notificationHubEntities'))]"
        },
        "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.NotificationHubs/namespaces', parameters('notificationHubName'))]"
        ],
        "properties": {
            "authorizationRules": []
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "Microsoft.NotificationHubs/namespaces/notificationHubs/authorizationRules",
        "apiVersion": "2017-04-01",
        "name": "[concat(parameters('notificationHubName'), '/',parameters('notificationHubEntities')[copyIndex()],'/DefaultFullSharedAccessSignature')]",
        "copy": {
            "name": "addNotificationHub",
            "count": "[length(parameters('notificationHubEntities'))]"
        },
        "tags": {
            "Environment": "[parameters('environment')]",
            "DisplayName": "Notification Hub Auth Rules"
        },
        "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.NotificationHubs/namespaces/notificationHubs',parameters('notificationHubName'), parameters('notificationHubEntities')[copyIndex()])]",
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.NotificationHubs/namespaces', parameters('notificationHubName'))]"
        ],
        "properties": {
            "rights": [
                "Listen",
                "Manage",
                "Send"
            ]
        }
    }        
],
"outputs": {
    "connectionStrings" :
    {
        "type": "array",
        "value": "[listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.NotificationHubs/namespaces/NotificationHubs/AuthorizationRules',parameters('notificationHubName'), parameters('notificationHubEntities')[copyIndex()], 'DefaultFullSharedAccessSignature'),'2016-03-01').primaryConnectionString]"   
    }
}
```

I've tried using object instead of array but to no avail, so I'm a bit confused, any help would be appreciated as the error message seems misleading to me or I'm just not interpreting it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish requirement of creating multiple notification hubs and it's authorization rules, you can use below ARM template.

Template Parameter File (notificationhub.parameters.json):

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "namespaceName": {
            "value": "mm-namespace"
        },
        "notificationhubNamePrefix": {
            "value": "mm-notificationhub"
        },
        "notificationhubAuthorizationruleNamePrefix": {
            "value": "mm-notificationhubAuthorizationrule"
        }
    }
}
```

Template File (notificationhub.json):

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "namespaceName": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "mm-namespace",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "namespaceName sample description"
            }
        },
        "notificationhubNamePrefix": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "mm-notificationhub",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "notificationhubName sample description"
            }
        },
        "notificationhubAuthorizationruleNamePrefix": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "mm-notificationhubAuthorizationrule",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "notificationhubAuthorizationruleName sample description"
            }
        },
        "location": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The location in which the resources should be deployed."
            }
        },
        "notificationhubNameSuffix": { 
            "type": "array", 
            "defaultValue": [ 
                "00", 
                "01", 
                "02" 
            ] 
        },
        "notificationhubAuthorizationruleNameSuffix": { 
            "type": "array", 
            "defaultValue": [ 
                "00", 
                "01", 
                "02" 
            ] 
        }
    },
    "variables": {},
    "resources": [
        {
            "name": "[parameters('namespaceName')]",
            "type": "Microsoft.NotificationHubs/namespaces",
            "apiVersion": "2017-04-01",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "tags": {},
            "sku": {
                "name": "Free"
            },
            "properties": {
                "namespaceType": "NotificationHub"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "[concat(parameters('namespaceName'), '/', parameters('notificationhubNamePrefix'), parameters('notificationhubNameSuffix')[copyIndex()])]",
            "type": "Microsoft.NotificationHubs/namespaces/notificationHubs",
            "apiVersion": "2017-04-01",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "sku": {
                "name": "Free"
            },
            "copy": {
                "name": "notificationhubscopy",
                "count": "[length(parameters('notificationhubNameSuffix'))]" 

            },
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.NotificationHubs/namespaces', parameters('namespaceName'))]"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "[concat(parameters('namespaceName'), '/', parameters('notificationhubNamePrefix'), parameters('notificationhubNameSuffix')[copyIndex()], '/', parameters('notificationhubAuthorizationruleNamePrefix'), parameters('notificationhubAuthorizationruleNameSuffix')[copyIndex()])]",
            "type": "Microsoft.NotificationHubs/namespaces/notificationHubs/AuthorizationRules",
            "apiVersion": "2017-04-01",
            "properties": {
                "rights": [
                    "Listen",
                    "Manage",
                    "Send"
                ]
            },
            "copy": {
                "name": "notificationhubsauthroizationrulescopy",
                "count": "[length(parameters('notificationhubAuthorizationruleNameSuffix'))]" 

            },
            "dependsOn": [
                "notificationhubscopy"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Deployment:

[image]

AFAIK, to accomplish requirement of getting output (in this case primaryConnectionStrings of multiple notification hubs' authorization rules) from ARM template is currently an unsupported feature. I already see related feature requests / feedback [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/281804-azure-resource-manager/suggestions/12881535-in-outputs-of-a-template-allow-to-return-the-refe) and [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/281804-azure-resource-manager/suggestions/37300390-arm-template-function-keys). I would recommend you to up-vote these feature requests / feedback or create a new feature request / feedback explaining your use case and requirement. Azure feature team would consider and work on the feature request / feedback based on the votes, visibility and priority on it.

Azure document references:

1. [ARM template reference for NotificationHubs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.notificationhubs/allversions)
2. [Resolve Invalid Template errors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-invalid-template-errors)
3. [Create multiple instances of a resource using copy and copyIndex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-multiple)
4. [ARM template functions like list (ListKeys)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-template-functions)
5. [ARM template structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-authoring-templates#outputs)
6. [Defining order for deploying resources in ARM templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-define-dependencies)

Hope this helps!! Cheers!!

Comment: thanks for your reply. The issue I had was the outputting of the keys, which seems to be unsupported. Thanks for confirming

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a copy loop in outputs today - listing the keys is fine, but you have to know how many you need at design time and hardcode each output.  We're working on a fix for that but not there yet.

You *could* emulate this by using your second option - deploying in a nested deployment and outputting each key in it's own deployment, but then you have to iterate through all the deployments to get all the outputs.